# Do you force yourself to eat Shalosh Seuda if you are not hungry?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, meal-seudah

Let's say on a short winter Shabbos you had a large meal on Friday night and another large midday meal on Shabbos day.  The midday meal lasts a few hours and now it is close to the end of the day.  You know it is an obligation to eat 3 meals on Shabbos, but the thought of eating anything else now is repulsive to you.  Can you say a bracha over bread when eating it would be repulsive to you?  What do you do?

Answer (score 9):

If eating is actually repulsive, at that point it is not considered halkhicaly eating and he will not fulfil his obligation of eating the third meal. See Mishna Berurah siman 291 #4.

As far as making a bracha on just such a non-eating, see Mishna Berurah siman 204 #48 concerning a food which one finds repulsive but is eating for health reasons, being that he gets no enjoyment from eating it, one does not make a blessing.

If however the person is not at the point of repulsion, but rather just not hungry, although he is no longer commanded to eat that third meal because the mitzvah of eating the meals was given to be enjoyed, not to be bothersome, see Mishna Berurah in 291 #3, apparently he may still eat and make blessings.

Answer (score 7):

Shulchan Arukh OC 291:1

> יהא זהיר מאד לקיים סעודה שלישית ואף אם הוא שבע יכול לקיים אותה בכביצה ואם אי אפשר לו כלל לאכול אינו חייב לצער את עצמו ו[החכם עיניו בראשו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3102.htm#14) שלא ימלא בטנו בסעודת הבוקר כדי ליתן מקום לסעודה שלישית:‏
>   One should be careful to fulfill The Third Meal, and even if he is satiated he can fulfill it with an egg's bulk. And if he is unable to eat at all he is not obligated to pain himself. And [a wise person thinks ahead] not filling his stomach in the morning meal so that he has room for The Third Meal.

Note the midday meal *is* The Third Meal. People would usually eat some food in the morning and at night. The special part of Shabbat was not working when you could eat lunch. Yum!

Comment: cause in those times people only ate only breakfast and supper, so by eating lunch - seudas shlisit - you would make it special, right?

Comment: @havarka That's kinda the idea. A husband has to give his wife two meals a day (EH 70:3). A poor person can collect money if he can't afford two meals a day (YD 253:1).

Comment: so davening vasikin and having and your second seudah is ideal? and seudah shlishit in the middle of the day is ideal, why then make it close to the end of shabbes?

Comment: @havarka You _can_ make it whenever you want in the afternoon. Many people nowadays like sleeping in and having shaloshudis closer to sunset. Ok. מה שגורם לספינתם לצוף as they say :)

Comment: @DoubleAA I know, you can make it whenever you want, but how is gonna be distinguished from a regular supper, if the main thing is the time when you eat it. I know there is melave malke, but then is like eating twice supper?

Comment: I think it's obvious that OP's evening meal is before sunset.

Comment: @joshua why are you telling me that?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Because I could only make sense of your answer if you think the evening meal is after sunset.

Comment: @Joshua I don't know what meal you are talking about. Usually you have a meal in the morning and at night. Breakfast and dinner. This happens on Friday as usual. On Saturday since there's no work you have time for lunch in the middle too. So the three meals on Shabbat are Friday dinner, Saturday breakfast, and Saturday lunch. The Melavveh Malka is Saturday dinner. Sunday has breakfast and dinner like usual. If someone wants to have a late breakfast and a late lunch and an early dinner, that's their prerogative.